# How do I view close votes?

Tags: support

According to the privilege list, I am supposed to be able to view close votes for a question.

Where is that option? I have been searching around for it but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would see it on the question, next to the close button - the number of votes will be in parentheses. However there are not currently any questions with close votes on it, so you'll have to wait to enjoy that dubious pleasure...

Comment: Does this mean i can see close votes on all questions, not just my own? Because i can only see the close button on my own questions as of now. The privilege page wasn't very clear about this point.

Comment: Hmm, that's right, casting a close vote requires 3000 rep. But yes, you should be able to see the close votes on all questions, not sure exactly how it will appear.